# Cant get variable in data

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I created a function that should set a var equal to a variable in data.

```
export default class App extends Vue{
  data() {
    return {
      evidence: 0
    }
  }
  handleFileSelect(evt: any) {
      var evidence = this.evidence;
  }
};
```

The problem is that it shows an error saying "Property 'evidence' does not exist on type 'App'".

Answer (score 2):

In vuejs functions should be in the methods section where you can use the data within the vue instance. Read here in [detail](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Method-Handler).

Hence your code should be as below.

```
export default class App extends Vue{
 data() {
    return {
      evidence: 0
    }
 },
 methods: {
  handleFileSelect(evt: any) {
      var evidence = this.evidence;
  }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no TypeScript guru, but this should work..

```
export default class App extends Vue{
  data() {
    return {
      evidence: 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
     handleFileSelect(evt: any) {
        let evidence = this.evidence;
     }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the decorator from [*vue-class-component*](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component):

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  evidence = 0
}
```